# How to get gunicorn to log uncaught exceptions?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I have a flask application wrapped with gunicorn. I would like that if one of my endpoints exits with an uncaught exception that somewhere the exception is logged. I don't want this going to the client however, just a  server logfile.

Comment: What have you tried? You'll need something like `try: working; except: log`.

Comment: Uncaught exceptions are those not contained in an `try` block. Presumably one of gunicorn/flask is catching them and swallowing. I have tried `app.errorhandler` but it appears to catch the intended HTTP errors as well (so anything from `abort` or status-code != 200)

Comment: teardown_request()?? This should catch all unhandled exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Config Flask PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS to True. This will enable propagation of exceptions, and gunicorn will log a logfile.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/#builtin-configuration-values

Answer (score 0):

Check `/var/log/upstart/myapp.log`

http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html#upstart